# Subsetting rows in R based on time intervals

Tags: r, time, subset, intervals

I have a series on GPS positions in POSIXlt format. I want to subset and retain only positions that where taken more than 5 minutes (300 seconds) appart.

I have the time interval in seconds between two consecutive position using subset(diff()). The problem I face is that my first three positions are 5 minutes appart each, so R doesn't return any of them (same thing happens further along my data frame)

What I'd like to get are position #1 and #3 (which are 10 minutes appart).
I want and drop #2 because it is 5 minutes from #1 and then check if the next position is >5 minutes appart from the last position I kept.

How should I proceed?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Could you include an example dataset using `dput()`?

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach would be to `diff`, remove anything too close to the previous observation, and repeat until you don't remove anything. However this could be quite inefficient for a large dataset with closely spaced observations.

A way to do this in a single pass would be to loop through the observations, accumulating the time differences as you skips observations that are too close to the last one that was kept:

```
# Use for loop to determine which to keep
pick.obs <- function(diffs, limit) {
  keep <- c(T, rep(F, length(diffs)))
  acc <- 0
  for (i in seq_along(diffs)) {
    acc <- acc + diffs[i]
    if (acc > limit) {
      keep[i+1] <- T
      acc <- 0
    }
  }
  return(keep)
}

# Observations at time 0, 300, 500, 700, 1700; limit 600 seconds
obs.times <- c(0, 300, 500, 700, 1700)
pick.obs(diff(obs.times), 600)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

One issue with this approach is that `for` loops in R are slow compared to vectorized operators. We can regain this speed by implementing this for loop in C++ (making only small syntactic changes) with the `Rcpp` package:

```
library(Rcpp)
pick.obs2 <- cppFunction(
"LogicalVector pickObs(NumericVector diffs, const double limit) {
  int n = diffs.size();
  LogicalVector keep(n + 1, false);
  keep[0] = true;
  double acc = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
    acc += diffs[i];
    if (acc > limit) {
      keep[i+1] = true;
      acc = 0;
    }
  }
  return keep;
}")
```

We can compare the performance of the pure-R version with the Rcpp version using `microbenchmark`:

```
# Reproducible example of time differences (10000 observations)
set.seed(144)
diffs <- runif(10000, 0, 20)
all.equal(pick.obs(diffs, 300), pick.obs2(diffs, 300))
# [1] TRUE

# Benchmark
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(pick.obs(diffs, 300), pick.obs2(diffs, 300))
# Unit: microseconds
#                   expr      min        lq       mean    median       uq       max neval
#   pick.obs(diffs, 300) 4494.029 4947.9140 6058.83941 5128.2535 6154.653 38302.461   100
#  pick.obs2(diffs, 300)   19.877   21.2015   32.02145   30.8515   34.654   178.031   100
```

The `Rcpp` version is about 200x faster on a vector of length 10000. Whether this speedup matters is entirely dependent on the size of your problem (e.g. you probably don't mind waiting 5 ms for a vector of length 10,000).

Comment: I have almost the same question here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38504957/regular-time-between-rows-with-r[link]. Can you give a bit more codes to apply the second solution you gave (the faster one...)

Comment: The length of "diffs" is 1 less than the result of pick.obs2. Why is that?

Comment: @Nova sorry, I'm not sure I follow the question. Which piece of code are you talking about?

Comment: In your example, if you run `diffs <- runif(100, 0, 20)` then run `keep <- pick.obs2(diffs, 300)`, the length of `diffs` is not the same as `keep`. If you wanted to use `keep` to remove obs from `diff`, the lengths are not equal.

Comment: @Nova got it. `pick.obs2` takes as an argument the differences between consecutive elements in your original list. So if `diffs` is of length 100, it must have come from some original list of length 101. So if you have an original vector like `obs.times <- c(0, 300, 500, 700, 1700)` then you can figure out whether to keep each with `pick.obs2(diff(obs.times), 300)`.