# Regular time between rows with R

Tags: r, time

I have this sample:

```
  structure(list(timestamp_pretty = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 2L, 11L, 15L, 
16L, 19L), .Label = c("01/06/2014 00:04:00", "01/06/2014 00:04:01", 
"01/06/2014 00:07:10", "01/06/2014 00:10:10", "01/06/2014 00:13:11", 
"01/06/2014 00:19:20", "01/06/2014 00:20:02", "01/06/2014 00:22:20", 
"01/06/2014 00:25:30", "01/06/2014 01:11:11", "01/06/2014 01:16:03", 
"01/06/2014 01:17:12", "01/06/2014 01:20:41", "01/06/2014 01:26:51", 
"01/06/2014 01:28:03", "01/06/2014 01:43:03", "01/06/2014 01:45:20", 
"01/06/2014 02:12:01", "01/06/2014 02:13:05", "01/06/2014 02:18:01"
), class = "factor"), mmsi = c(205477000L, 205477000L, 205477000L, 
205477000L, 205477000L, 205477000L, 205477000L, 205477000L, 205477000L, 
205477000L, 205477000L, 205477000L, 205477000L, 205477000L, 205477000L, 
205482000L, 205482000L, 205482000L, 205482000L, 205482000L)), .Names = c("timestamp_pretty", 
"mmsi"), row.names = c(8L, 9L, 17L, 16L, 4L, 12L, 3L, 14L, 10L, 
7L, 13L, 19L, 6L, 15L, 1L, 11L, 18L, 20L, 2L, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

the column `diff_time_seconds_timestamp_pretty`is the difference of time between the rows by `mmsi`.

I would like to remove some signals (rows) and to keep only the signals every XXX seconds (for example 180 seconds) for each `mmsi`.

My thought was to use the package `zoo`, it seems to be done for this. But I could not manage so I am now looking to:

1. Add the cum sum of the `diff_time_seconds_timestamp_pretty` per mmsi
2. to remove the signals that are less than 180 seconds from eachother.
3. To keep the signals that are at least 180 seconds from eachother

I try to work with

```
library(dplyr)
test <- data %>% 
  group_by(mmsi) %>%
  mutate(cum.sum=cumsum(diff_time_seconds_timestamp_pretty))
```

but it seems that I am still far from what I want.

Help is welcome!

Comment: Can you add your expected output? Something like `df %>% group_by(mmsi) %>% mutate(diff_time = timestamp_pretty - lag(timestamp_pretty)) %>% filter(diff_time >= 180)` would work?

Comment: That could work. I will continue to work with this a basis, thanks. The output is a bit hard to produce. I only know that most of the signals are every 10 seconds, and I would like to have signals only every 3 or 4 minutes.

Comment: The thing with that solution is that it also eliminates the very first observation, which can be fixed, but cum sum is the most confusing here. Also note that I converted `timestamp_pretty` to `POSIXct` i.e. `df$timestamp_pretty <- as.POSIXct(df$timestamp_pretty, format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: True, it would be better to keep the first record / observation. Why cumsum is confusing here? I am just looking to have a regular time serie, I thought cumsum could help to go to the next signals within XXX seconds

Answer (score 3):

Here are two approaches which divide the datetimes into 180 second intervals and then keep only the last data point in each.

**1) chron/zoo** Convert the time stamps to chron and use `trunc.times` from that package to truncate them to every 180 seconds (i.e. every 3 minutes).  Then read them into zoo aggregating on equal date/times using the `tail` function so that only the last gets retained:

```
library(chron)
library(zoo)
# return the chron date time at start of 180 sec interval each point is in
to180ch <- function(x) trunc(as.chron(as.character(x), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"), "00:03:00")
read.zoo(data, FUN = to180ch, aggregate = function(x) tail(x, 1))
```

The result is the following zoo object that uses chron date/times:

```
(01/06/14 00:03:00) (01/06/14 00:06:00) (01/06/14 00:09:00) (01/06/14 00:12:00) 
          205482000           205477000           205477000           205477000 
(01/06/14 00:18:00) (01/06/14 00:21:00) (01/06/14 00:24:00) (01/06/14 01:09:00) 
          205477000           205477000           205477000           205477000 
(01/06/14 01:15:00) (01/06/14 01:18:00) (01/06/14 01:24:00) (01/06/14 01:27:00) 
          205482000           205477000           205477000           205482000 
(01/06/14 01:42:00) (01/06/14 01:45:00) (01/06/14 02:12:00) (01/06/14 02:18:00) 
          205482000           205477000           205482000           205477000
```

If what is preferred is to just subset the data frame down to 180 second intervals then try this:

```
subset(data, !duplicated(to180ch(timestamp_pretty), fromLast = TRUE))
```

**2) No packages**  Convert to POSIXct and then numeric, perform the truncation and convert back to POSIXct.  Finally `aggregate` using `tail`:

```
# return the POSIXct date time at start of 180 sec interval each point is in
to180ct <- function(x) {
    p <- as.POSIXct(as.character(x), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    as.POSIXct(180 * as.numeric(p) %/% 180, origin = "1970-01-01")
}
aggregate(data[2], list(timestamp = to180ct(data[[1]])), tail, 1)
```

giving this data frame with a POSIXct `timestamp`:

```
             timestamp      mmsi
1  2014-01-06 00:03:00 205482000
2  2014-01-06 00:06:00 205477000
3  2014-01-06 00:09:00 205477000
4  2014-01-06 00:12:00 205477000
5  2014-01-06 00:18:00 205477000
6  2014-01-06 00:21:00 205477000
7  2014-01-06 00:24:00 205477000
8  2014-01-06 01:09:00 205477000
9  2014-01-06 01:15:00 205482000
10 2014-01-06 01:18:00 205477000
11 2014-01-06 01:24:00 205477000
12 2014-01-06 01:27:00 205482000
13 2014-01-06 01:42:00 205482000
14 2014-01-06 01:45:00 205477000
15 2014-01-06 02:12:00 205482000
16 2014-01-06 02:18:00 205477000
```

As in (1) if what is wanted is just to subset the data frame then just replace `to180ch` in the `subset` line in (1) with `to180ct` like this:

```
subset(data, !duplicated(to180ct(timestamp_pretty), fromLast = TRUE))
```

Comment: Very good solutions. I found out that the results are different between the two solutions. Sometimes the interval is a bit less than 3 minutes but it could be enough for me here, I just want to remove extra rows... Which solutions is the best for you? I will test on a bigger sample to make sure that it does not change my data (I have several other columns...) and I will come back here! I also have to edit a bit to make it working for each mmsi

Comment: and I add to change  the date format `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S` to `%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S`

Comment: do you think the loop `for ( i in levels(data$mmsi) ){
  read.zoo(data, FUN = to180ch, aggregate = function(x) tail(x, 1))}

test <- subset(data, !duplicated(to180ch(timestamp_pretty), fromLast = TRUE))
test <- test[order(test$mmsi, test$timestamp_pretty),]` is giving a good result for each `mmsi` levels? I have been trying to run your solution 1 for each mmsi instead than for all the table, but I could not find the solution...

Comment: @G. Grothendieck, I want to develop auto.arima model from multiple time series data and I want to use 1 year of data, 3 year of data, 5, 7... in a two year interval  from each series and testing it in testing set. How do I do the subsetting so that the fitted model will have what I want? I appreciate for your help

Comment: If you are using zoo or xts you can use the window function.